How to use the Repository Pattern implementations passing object T and maintain using Models
I have been trying to use a repository pattern; therefore, I have a repository that inherits another base class with basic CRUD commands. However, I am running into conflict with my naming conventions; it looks like even though passing models was the entire point of the repository pattern and using them in the data layer.
For instance, I was under the assumption using T as the base class allowed me to pass an expected object type through my application layers. This object type is a model, though, which I use in each layer. However, I am getting issues where it says I need to declare the namespace in front of the model object because it interferes with the T base class I am assigning to that implementation:
using ARMS_API.Models;
using Dapper;

namespace ARMS_API.Repositories
{
    public class CertificationReviewRepository<CertificationReview> : IRepository <CertificationReview> where CertificationReview : class
    {
        private readonly DbContext _context;
        public CertificationReviewRepository(DbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public CertificationReview Create(CertificationReview certificationReview)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<CertificationReview> ReadAsync(CertificationReview certificationReview)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();

        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<CertificationReview>> ReadAllAsync()
        {
            using(var connection = _context.CreateConnection())
            {
                var certificationReviews = await connection.QueryAsync<ARMS_API.Models.CertificationReview, State, ARMS_API.Models.Program, ActuarialFirm, User , User, User , ARMS_API.Models.CertificationReview>("select * from dbo.A2F_DMCP_0005_BrowseTest()",
                map: (certificationReview , state , program , actuarialFirm , primaryActuary , secondaryActuary , dmcpAnalyst ) => {
                    certificationReview.State = state;
                    state.Programs.Add(program);
                    certificationReview.ActuarialFirm = actuarialFirm;
                    certificationReview.PrimaryReviewer = primaryActuary;
                    certificationReview.SecondaryReviewer = secondaryActuary;
                    certificationReview.DMCPAnalyst = dmcpAnalyst;
                    return certificationReview;
                },
                splitOn: "STATE_ID,PROGRAM_DD,ACTUARIAL_FIRM_DD,CERTIFYING_ACTUARY_ID,PRIMARY_ACTUARY_ID,SECONDARY_ACTUARY_ID,DMCP_ANALYST_ID");
                return certificationReviews;
            }        
        }

        public CertificationReview Update(CertificationReview certificationReview)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

However, my base class for the repository is as follows:
namespace ARMS_API.Repositories
{
    public interface IRepository <T> where T : class
    {
        T Create (T entity);
        Task<T> ReadAsync (T entity);
        Task<IEnumerable<T>> ReadAllAsync ();
        T Update (T entity);
    }
}

And I have a model I created as follows:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace ARMS_API.Models
{
   public class CertificationReview
     {
        [JsonPropertyName("MMCID")]
        [Column("MMCID")]
        public int? MMCID {get; set;}

        [JsonPropertyName("OLD_TRACKER_NAME")]
        [Column("OLD_TRACKER_NAME")]        
        public string? TrackerName {get; set;}

        [JsonPropertyName("STATE")]
        [Column("STATE")]             
        public State? State {get; set;}

        [JsonPropertyName("CERTIFICATION_DATE")]
        [Column("CERTIFICATION_DATE")]  
        public DateTime? SignatureDate {get; set;}

        [JsonPropertyName("RATING_PERIOD_BEGINS")]
        [Column("RATING_PERIOD_BEGINS")]  
        public DateTime? RatingPeriodBeginDate {get; set;}

        [JsonPropertyName("RATING_PERIOD_ENDS")]
        [Column("RATING_PERIOD_ENDS")]  
        public DateTime? RatingPeriodEndDate {get; set;}

        [JsonPropertyName("PRIMARY_REVIEWER")]
        [Column("PRIMARY_REVIEWER")]  
        public User? PrimaryReviewer {get; set;}

        [JsonPropertyName("SECONDARY_REVIEWER")]
        [Column("SECONDARY_REVIEWER")]  
        public User? SecondaryReviewer {get; set;}

        [JsonPropertyName("ACTUARIAL_FIRM")]
        [Column("ACTUARIAL_FIRM")]  
        public ActuarialFirm? ActuarialFirm {get; set;}

        [JsonPropertyName("DMCP_ANALYST")]
        [Column("DMCP_ANALYST")]  
        public User? DMCPAnalyst {get; set;}
    }

    public class State
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("STATE_ID")]
        [Column("STATE_ID")]     
        public required int Id {get; set;}

        [JsonPropertyName("ENTITY_NAME")]
        [Column("ENTITY_NAME")]    
        public required string Name {get; set;}

        [JsonPropertyName("PROGRAMS")]
        [Column("PROGRAMS")]
        public List<Program> Programs { get; set; } = new List<Program>();
    }

    public class Program
    {

        [JsonPropertyName("PROGRAM_DD")]
        [Column("PROGRAM_DD")]           
        public required int Id {get; set;}

        [JsonPropertyName("PROGRAM_SHORT_NAME")]
        [Column("PROGRAM_SHORT_NAME")]   
        public required string Name {get; set;}
    }
    
    public class ActuarialFirm
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("ACTUARIAL_FIRM_DD")]
        [Column("ACTUARIAL_FIRM_DD")]   
        public required int Id {get; set;}

        [JsonPropertyName("FIRM_NAME")]
        [Column("FIRM_NAME")]   
        public required string Name {get; set;}

        [JsonPropertyName("CERTIFYING_ACTUARY")]
        [Column("CERTIFYING_ACTUARY")]
        public List<User>? Actuaries {get; set;}
    }
}

It is unclear why I do not put ARMS_API.Models.CertificationReview in my dapper mapping, then all the parameters in the mapping, it says, cannot find a definition. However, if I keep this strict namespace naming convention then I get the following error on certificationReview I am trying to return in my mapping:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ARMS_API.Models.CertificationReview>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CertificationReview>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)CS0266

Also, it's probably unrelated, but the [Columns()] attribute does not seem to do the translation and connect the dots to the results when I do a strict typecast to make this work.

If  you resolve your issue ?
If not, could you please follow up to let me know?
